# Google Sites custom domain redirecting is in infinite loop

Tags: dns, google-workspace, google-sites, redirect-loop

TL;DR Google Sites goes into an infinite redirect loop and I can't figure out why.

I'm setting up a website for my NPO (that means Google Workspace non-profit licence). We recently acquired a Google Workspace licence, I have since bound our domain to it and set up our email service - all of that is working nicely.

I also moved our Google Sites site to my Workspace account. The site (on Google's domain) itself works nicely, but in Google Sites settings menu there is no custom domain option that is shown on Google in several threads. "That's fine" - I thought - "I'll just set it up in the Admin panel under Apps -> Workspace -> Sites -> Custom URL and it'll work nicely." - I thought. Well I set it up through that menu and as a "Status" it shows a green checkmark (see picture below), but in reality Firefox says there is an issue with the cookies and Chrome says ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. In fact, when testing with Where Goes it does tell me there is an infinite redirect loop.

I tried redoing the whole process of adding the custom URL to sites in Google Admin panel with no changes and contacting Google Workspace support, but they told me I needed to wait 48 hours for "changes to happen" (but we all know nothing's going to happen in that time)... It has now been 24 hours and I believe with community assistance I can get it working earlier than tomorrow night.

The domain I'm trying to redirect is [www.teadusklubi.ee](http://www.teadusklubi.ee) and the site itself has an URL of: https://sites.google.com/teadusklubi.ee/teadusklubi
(I also attached a picture of my DNS Records, I redacted some info, the first 4 are related to the naked domain setup in Google Workspace and the last one is the Google domain verification, I'm not sure if I should have hidden that info but I want to stay safe :) )

Any help is appreciated, any questions you give me - I'll answer quickly :)
[Sites Custom URL status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6iJ7.png)
[DNS Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW8Cm.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the Name Servers are misconfigured, at this moment it seems like there is no Cname record configured: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/www.teadusklubi.ee

confiuring Cnames is required for a domain to work with the redirection as the domain you are trying to redirect contains a subdomain *(the www part is considered a sub domain in this situation)*.

The actual Cname ghs.googlehostes.com. as mentioned here: [https://support.google.com/a/answer/7392423?hl=en&fl=1#:~:text=(Optional)%20To%20update%20the%20CNAME%20record%20on%20your%20domain%20host%E2%80%99s%20website%3A](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7392423?hl=en&fl=1#:%7E:text=(Optional)%20To%20update%20the%20CNAME%20record%20on%20your%20domain%20host%E2%80%99s%20website%3A) *(Please note that it is marked as "optional" however this is required, I believe that this might be due to Google taking into consideration Google domains which would have that setup automatically)*

I took a look and it seems likely that you might have changed your name servers as they are currently pointing to cloudflare: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/teadusklubi.ee which is typically used to manage websites but since you want to use a Google Site you will need to change that back to your default DNS if you happen to have any

Hope this helps!

Comment: The CNAME URL should be `ghs.googlehosted.com`